# Laurent Series of $1/f(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $f(z) = z + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{3}z^{3} + \ldots $ be the Taylor series of $f$ which is valid for $ \vert z \vert < 1$.

I want to prove that the Laurent series of $g(z) = 1/f(1/z)$ is of the form $g(z) = z + b_{0} + b_{1}/z + b_{2}/z^{2} + \ldots $ which is valid for $ \vert z \vert > 1$.

I found that $z^{2}f(1/z) = z + a_{2} +a_{3}/z + \ldots$, but how can I associate it with $1/f(1/z)$?

Comment: Do you mean $z^2 f(1/z) = z + a_2 + a_3/z +\dots$?

Comment: yes. I edit it.

Comment: You want to prove a thing which is simply not there. Say, if $f$ has a root at $z=\frac12$, then your series for $f$ might well have the said form, but the series for $1/f$ will break.

Comment: Sorry. I have condition that $f$ is injective, so that $1/f(1/z)$ is analytic since $f(1/z)=0$ will break injectivity as $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see it is as follows. Let's say $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^{-n}$ (you already know that it is analytic). Then,
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{g(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{zf(1/z)}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+a_2/z+a_3/z^2+\dots}=1$$
But this can only be the case for $b_{-1}=1$ and $b_{-n}=0$ for $n\geq2$ since
$$\frac{g(z)}{z}=\underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^{-n-1}\right)}_{\to 0 \text{ when } z\to\infty}+b_0+b_{-1}z+b_{-2}z^2+\dots$$

Another equivalent way to see it is the following one. Notice that $g(1/z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n z^{n}$. Then, it can be analogously checked that $\lim_{z\to0}zg(1/z)=\lim_{z\to0}z/f(z)=1$ which necessarily implies that $b_{-1}=1$ and that $b_{-2}=b_{-3}=\dots=0$.

Comment: Thanks! Can we explicitly determine $b_{1}$ when $a_{2} =0$? My book says that $b_{1} = -a_{3}$, but I cannot get explicit form if I follow this argument.

Comment: @KimSeongHyeon Now that you know that $g(z) = z + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^{-n}$ you can see that
$$1=g(z)f(1/z)=(z+b_0+b_1 z^{-1}+\dots)(z^{-1}+a_3 z^{-3}+\dots)=1+b_0z^{-1}+(b_1+a_3)z^{-2}+\dots$$
(that is, examining the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)) which implies that $b_0=0$ and $b_1=-a_3$ whenever $a_2=0$ (since $1=1+0z^{-1}+0z^{-2}+\dots$) if I'm not mistaken.